# Resharper - Navigate to ASCX Register/ Usage

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

Is there a way I can navigate to files that have a select ascx registered?

**For example:**

If I am in a project with 'dog.ascx', 'cat.ascx' and 'rat.ascx'. 
Cat and Rat both have:

```
<%@ Register src="~/.../dog.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="Dog" %>
```

Is there a shortcut such that when I'm in dog.ascx will pull up a list with cat and rat?

- *Resharper: 10*
- *VS: 2013 Ultimate*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use (Ctrl + Shift + F) to bring up "Find In Files" and search for **TagName="Dog"**

Comment: This was a while back and I don't remember if I considered this. But it seems like a rather good and obvious way. Thanks.